# "zsh: event not found:" How to exclude files from git on mac bash?

Tags: git, command-line, zsh

I have a lot of files that I want to add to my commit, but I want to exclude a couple of folders and files.

We have a script that does this on Windows, but it doesn't work when running on Mac's zsh bash terminal.

This is what it looks like:

```
git add -A -- :!snippets/elevar-body-end.liquid :!snippets/elevar-checkout-end.liquid :!snippets/elevar-head.liquid :!layout/theme.liquid :!sections/footer.liquid :!config/*
```

When we run it on mac, this is the error we get:

```
zsh: event not found: snippets/elevar
```

How should we modify our script so that it runs on both Windows and Mac?

Comment: Have you looked at [.gitgnore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)?  I don't know about windows, but this works on Macs.

Comment: `zsh` and `bash` are two separate shells, and both are independent of the terminal emulator they run in. You aren't using `bash` at all, only `zsh`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bzsh%5D+event+not+found

Answer (score 1):

Add the files and folder you want to ignore in the [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file.

Add the .gitignore file to `git add .gitignore`

Commit the .gitignore `git commit -m "Creating list of ignored files/folder"`

Now every file/folder in the .gitginore will be, of course, ignored and won't be tracked by git.

You could also try adding quotes to the excluded files.

`git add -A -- ':!snippets/elevar-body-end.liquid' ':!snippets/elevar-checkout-end.liquid'`